# Seeking Guidance on Predictive Maintenance with Censored Data

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, dataset, engineering-statistics

I am currently immersed in a project centered around predictive maintenance for hardware components. The primary objective is to anticipate the impending failure of hardware components or estimate their remaining operational lifespan. However, a notable challenge confronts me due to the distinctive characteristics of the data available for this endeavor.

Here's a succinct overview of the scenario:

We've recently implemented a data collection mechanism designed to gather the requisite conditional attributes for our predictive model. Furthermore, we've developed an automated technique to accurately tag instances of component failure. **The crux of the issue lies in the fact that we're procuring data from hardware components that have been in service for a considerable duration.** Regrettably, information pertinent to their historical usage patterns or operational conditions is conspicuously absent.

To elaborate further:

To predict the likelihood of an impending failure, it is imperative to possess knowledge about the extent to which the hardware has been utilized. Consider the analogy of cars equipped with mileage indicators, which offer owners insights into the amount their vehicles have been used. It stands to reason that a car with 500,000 kilometers on the odometer is more susceptible to mechanical issues than one that has only covered 20 kilometers.

This encapsulates the core of my predicament: **I am working to predict hardware failures, but my dataset is missing usage history information for each individual hardware unit prior to the new implementation of our data collection service.**

Our data looks like:
[image]

Any insights, methodologies, or best practices that you could share would be immensely valuable in guiding me towards achieving accurate predictive maintenance results despite the limitations of our dataset.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise. I look forward to learning from your experience and knowledge in the field of data science and predictive maintenance.

Best regards.